# Cannot read sections of config files containing []

Tags: python

*Edited post*

I'm not able to read the configuration file sections that contain `[]`... for e.g if any section in ini file is something like `[c:\\temp\\foo[1].txt]` than my script fails to read that section..

```
config.read(dst_bkp)
for i in config.sections():
    config.get(i,'FileName')
```

Thanks,
Vignesh

Comment: Please state that `config` is an instance of a subclass of `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you use a builtin subclass of `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser` module: This is not supported. Even in the [newest revision](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/ConfigParser.py?revision=81008&view=markup), the regex for section headers is just

```
SECTCRE = re.compile(
    r'\['                                 # [
    r'(?P<header>[^]]+)'                  # very permissive!
    r'\]'                                 # ]
    )
```

There is no escaping mechanism, and the section header simply ends at the first closing brackets. You should only use simple strings without "special characters" as header names, not arbitrary strings like file names.

**EDIT:** Concerning Python 3, the [equivalent code](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/py3k/Lib/configparser.py?revision=83889&view=markup) has been reorganized a bit, but the regex is the same:

```
_SECT_TMPL = r"""
    \[                                 # [
    (?P<header>[^]]+)                  # very permissive!
    \]                                 # ]
    """
```

**EDIT 2:** You can make your own subclass, as suggested in the other solution, or patch `RawConfigParser` directly:

```
import ConfigParser
import re
ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.SECTCRE = re.compile(r"\[(?P<header>.+)\]")
```

However, I'd suggest not doing any of these and avoid the brackets instead. If you have brackets in section headers, your configuration files are likely to be unportable.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because of the regexp used to parse the header -- it goes only as far as the first closing bracket.

You can fix it for your program by subclassing `ConfigParser.ConfigParser`:

```
import ConfigParser
import re

class MyConfigParser(ConfigParser.ConfigParser):
    SECTCRE = re.compile(
        r'\['                                 # [
        r'(?P<header>.+)'                     # even more permissive!
        r'\]'                                 # ]
        )

config = MyConfigParser()
config.read(dst_bkp)
for i in config.sections():
    config.get(i,'FileName')
```